# Как сделать так, чтобы персонаж поворачивался за джойстиком в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Как сделать так, чтобы персонаж поворачивался за джойстиком (по направлению движения) в unity? Нужно, чтобы персонаж поворачивался и двигался по направлению джойстика. Используется ассет "Joystick pack". С данным кодом персонаж двигается, но не поворачивается в направлении движения.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class moving : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;
    private float moveInput;
    public Joystick joystick;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    public bool moveright;
    public bool moveleft;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveInput = joystick.Vertical;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        moveInput = joystick.Horizontal;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.x);

    }
    private void Update()
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, локальная ось X смотрит туда же, куда и "перед", тогда нужно совместить эту ось с направлением движения, это `rb.velocity`.

Получается: `transform.right = rb.velocity;`

Добавьте это после изменения `rb.velocity`